# Prepending all linkable items in a textview with http://

Tags: java, android

I have a textview that displays html.

```
> textview.setText(html.fromhtml(document))
> textview.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

When i go to click on some of the links, some open in browser, others don't.

Logcat says this:

```
> No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW
> dat=law.fordham.edu/ (has extras) }
```

Seems like a simple fix. Just have to add "http://" to every link in the doc.

If all of the links started with "www", things would be easy. I would just do:

```
> replaceAll("www", "http://www")
```

That does work for some of the links. But not all of them start with 'www' and therefore, I need a different method to prepend them with http://

What is the best way to do this?

EDIT:

```
paragraphs = doc.select("div.sectionContent>*");
       set =  paragraphs.toString().replaceAll("\\\\n", "\n").trim();
       links = doc.select("a");
           for (Element i: links){
                  String relHref = i.attr("abs:href");
                  if (!relHref.contains("http")){
                       set = set.replace(relHref, "http://"+relHref);
                  }
                                 }
```

I'm using jsoup to do all this but I keep getting:

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
```

Answer (score 1):

Process the HTML, look for `<a>` tags and then if the start of the url inside the anchor is not what you want then adjust it.

A regex search should be able to find the anchors for you.